# SQL Server 2008 component is cluster-aware?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, clustering

Which SQL Server 2008 components are cluster-aware?

1. Notification Services
2. Tuning Advisor
3. Full Text Search
4. Reporting Services
5. Integration Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179410%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> A failover cluster instance can run on one or more computers that are
>   participating nodes of a failover cluster. **A failover cluster instance
>   contains**:
>
> - A combination of one or more disks in a Microsoft Cluster Service (MSCS) cluster group, also known as a resource group. Each resource
>     group can contain at most one instance of SQL Server.
> - A network name for the failover cluster instance.
> - One or more IP addresses assigned to the failover cluster instance.
> - **One instance of SQL Server that includes SQL Server, SQL Server Agent, the Full-text Search (FTS) service, and Replication. You can
>     install a failover cluster with SQL Server only, Analysis Services
>     only, or SQL Server and Analysis Services.**

I would suggest reviewing all the documentation on MSDN very carefully before attempting to create a failover cluster in your environment, as there are many considerations and requirements.